# sendmail send but no new email

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a problem with "sendmail". So if I type in:

```
echo "something" | sendmail -v "test mail" myemail@yahoo.com
```

I get the message:

```
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.
```

But when I check the email there is nothing new. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: What does your mailserver logs contain?

Comment: There's different output given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/586699/5132 .